# nfdump schedule with cron

Tags: scripts, backup, cron

Hi I tried to generate nfdump file with crontab, but whatever the reason it dosent work

my script

```
#!/bin/bash
nfdump -mR /home/user/test -zw /data/fnf1.dump
```

this script itself works and all other nfdump command on crontab work, basically this command create one dump file from bunch of files in a directory

Comment: Can you please show how you're configuring `crontab` to runn your script? Also, you say it doesn't work, what are the symptoms you see, does it simply not run or does it generate an error message? check `/var/log/syslog` for any error messages from `CRON`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the concern , syslog show below massage ,Feb 18 14:51:01 SiLk cron[670]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Feb 18 14:51:01 SiLk CRON[8750]: (root) CMD (/data/test.sh )
Feb 18 14:51:01 SiLk CRON[8749]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
crontab only put ,51 14   * * * /data/test.sh

Comment: so your cron entry is `51 14 * * * /data/test.sh` ? this means you want the command to run at 2:51 PM every day, right? did you confirm that `/data/test.sh` is executable? Everything else looks fine to me. Note that cron tried to send you a message with more details but it was discarded as you don't have a mail transport agent. I suggest you have your command logging to a file: `51 14 * * * /data/test.sh >/tmp/cron.log 2>&1` and then look at `/tmp/cron.log` to see why it fails.

Comment: hi appreciate your help so much, this is all about my lacking knowledge about cron, once i give the absolute path to my tool it work perfectly, 51 14 just random time to check config , tks

Answer (score 0):

OPs answer, taken from comments

> … this is all about my lacking knowledge about cron, once i give the
>   absolute path to my tool it work perfectly …